# Hotkeys not working or intersecting with OS

Tags: linux, keymap

I got a keymap problem:

I am using Blender on Linux (Arch) now and some keys are intersecting with the Linux hotkeys, like alt click and drag for moving a window but thats the same as edge select. I managed to rebind alt to super key now but still alt + shift + click is not working. Just nothing happens at all. Not in Linux. Not in Blender. Is there any for linux configured keymap i can downlaod? Or which other shortcut settings in the OS itself should I tweak? I need to relearn many hotkeys anyway coming from windows.

Maybe there is a way to prioritise blender hotkeys over Linux hotkeys?

---

Reinstalled and now its fixed for whatever reason

Comment: That's a common issue. I'd suggest just disable the hotkey which allows to drag the window, annoying for all other tools as well.

Comment: as i said, i alr rebinded alt to super key but i still had trouble with some "combined" hotkeys. like alt + shift or ctrl + shift. reinstallation and it got fixed. i honestly dont know what was the cause but thanks for your effort :)